# Divide database results in to 4 groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*(I have a Ruby/Rails/Postgres setup here.)*

I have a table of hundreds of thousands of artists and each day I run a background job that updates various external sources on those artists.

Doing that all at once every day overwhelms those external APIs, so I want to divide up that table in to 4 groups and then run those background jobs 4 times a day (i.e. every 6 hours).

How can I divide those database results in to 4 groups?

Initially I was just going to do 2 groups and then query based on "if artist ID is even/odd", but not sure how to do it for 4 groups.

Is there some sort of mathematical equation that can properly put any number in to one of 4 groups?

Ideally I'd do this in the query itself (`Artist.where("id % 2 = ?", "0")`), but if it makes more sense to filter the resulting array afterwards, that's fine as well.

Comment: Can't you use `Artist.where("id % 4 = ?", 0)`?. Then 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: May be you can run as batches. See https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

Comment: @Pablo I believe that'd get me duplicate IDs as numbers that are divisible by 4 would also be divisible by 2 and then `id % 1` would match basically every number.

Comment: @Pavan Totally. But this is for figuring out _which_ batch to consistently run.

Comment: You don't need anyspecial criteria? I mean, it can be devided in 4 groups with no other conditions? why not just count the total, divide by 4 and use offset and limit to select each block?

Comment: Is there anychance that database gets new records in between 2 runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run these queries (one every 6 hours)

```
Artist.where("id % 4 = ?", 0) #Run at 00:00

Artist.where("id % 4 = ?", 1) #Run at 06:00

Artist.where("id % 4 = ?", 2) #Run at 12:00

Artist.where("id % 4 = ?", 3) #Run at 18:00
```

Comment: Smart approach!

Answer (score 1):

You could just count the total, divide and use offset and limit:

```
group_amount = Model.all.count/4

scope = Model.limit(group_amount)

first_group = scope
second_group = scope.offset(group_amount)
third_group = scope.offset(group_amount*2)
fourth_group = Model.offset(group_amount*3) #not using limit in case you have new record on that table
```

I'm not sure it fill all your need, I don't know if you have some other criteria.